# forms builder or survey software or CRM or CMS or DMS allowing Editing of the responses

Tags: open-source, database, forms, survey

1. Custom fields
2. A forms builder or survey software or CRM or CMS or DMS which allows Editing of the responses
3. Each response can be edited only by the user who answered the survey questions
4. Maintains a history or versioning of the edits

LimeSurvey almost satisfies my criteria but does not allow editing of survey responses or authentication per survey response or versions of edits.

It doesn't even have to be a survey software, it can be any software which creates a row record in the database table and which allows only THAT particular user to edit that record and maintains a version of edits preferably. It needs custom fields. It can be a CRM or CMS or Document management system or  invoice software anything any CRUD software.

Software can be open-source, paid solutions are acceptable as well.

Comment: You may want to take a look at PollUnit (https://pollunit.com). Edits will be stored in the activity log, so this is not really a history or versioning feature. But it could meet your requirements.